# How can I make me Intersection Observer only put the div on the screen once and not remove it when the user scrolls away?

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I'm lazyloading an ad into my website, and I can get it to show up only when the user scrolls down far enough, but when the user scrolls back up, the div disappears. I want it so that when the user sees the div for the first time, the ads come and **stay there** even if he scrolls away. I also don't want the ads refreshing. My code is:

```
export const handleAds = () => {

  var myAds;

  window.addEventListener("load", function(event){
    myAds = document.querySelector("#theDiv");
    createObserver();
  },false);

  function createObserver(){
    var observer;

    var options = {
      root: null,
      rootMargin: "0px",
      threshold: 0.2
    };

    observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersect, options);
    observer.observe(myAds);

  }


  function handleIntersect(entries,observer){

    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++){
      if(entries[i].isIntersecting){
        //ad script
        }
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to float the div to some absolute position on the screen, but ONLY if the user first scrolls to it.  Is that correct?

Comment: well the div is at a certain position on the screen and when it comes into view, that's when I want it shown and the ads in that div @Abel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call `unobserve` in your callback:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/unobserve

```
function handleIntersect(entries,observer){

  for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++){
    if(entries[i].isIntersecting){
      //ad script
      observer.unobserve(entries[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work @James-South ; I also get `TypeError: Argument 1 of IntersectionObserver.unobserve does not implement interface Element.` EDIT: your solution did it, tho the argument you fed into unobserve was wrong